# Start X client in a bash script end exit script

Tags: bash, shell-script, x-server

I need to launch a xserver client process in a script and then exit from the script keeping the new process running:

```
#!/bin/bash

startx /home/me/my_x_client
exit 0
```

but in this way x terminates with the script.How can I start it in a new process and make init its direct parent?Or should I do it with the X server?
Should a process's fatherhood be directly assigned to init when the parent dies?

Comment: It should work. Change it to `startx /home/me/my_x_client > /tmp/my.log 2>&1` and `cat` the log to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup startx /home/me/my_x_client &
```

according to `man nohup`

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

Comment: I found nohup usefully only for interactive shells, maybe im wrong? In my bash version, in non-interactive shell script & will do the same effect effect of nohup without any other help, am i wrong?

Comment: Like this: 
timerf(){

 sleep 10
 echo "yes timer is still running"

}

timerf&

exit

Answer (score 0):

This is not working?

```
#!/bin/bash
startx /home/me/my_x_client &
exit 0
```

Comment: I tried it but the screen gets black , instead without & it turn back to the prompt

Comment: In what moment you are calling this script, for example, what services is system iniatiating at the moment?

Comment: I'm running a c++ qt application,when a button is clicked a bash script is launched.This script kill the c++ process and run the command    startx /usr/local/bin/xinput_calibrator i tried sudo startx /usr/local/bin/xinput_calibrator  -- :1 and sudo startx /usr/local/bin/xinput_calibrator --:1 & no one does work

Comment: If some services starts after Xorg, sometimes it just brokes... What if you guarantee all the services is started before Xorg?